# Format Cell Contents

Tags: excel, vba

I'm working from a software that stores some entity IDs and need to format them in a very specific way. I'll try to be as specific as possible.

Each cell has to be 6 digits long.

1st digit can be either alphabetical or numeric.

2nd, 3rd, and 4th digit can only be numeric.

5th and 6th digit can only be alphabetic.

I have some of the following IDs (and what i need them to look like) for example (substituting - for spaces):

> G11R(G-11R-), J6R(J--6R-), I6AR(I--6AR), 1516B(1516B-), 414(-414--).

I don't even know where to begin on something like this, I've searched the forum but I'm also not even sure exactly what you would call this.

Any help, even just a point in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: are you just trying to remove the blanks in your IDs?

Comment: @pokemon_Man what the OP wants is what is inside the `()` what they are given is in front.

Comment: No, I'm trying to add spaces to match the format I described. If A=alphabetical, N=numeric, and E= either, I need them in a format that looks like ENNNAA. So if i have "G11R" i need to add one space between the G and the 1 and a space after the R to get "G 11R ".

Comment: You're going to have to determine clear and specific rules for when spaces are being added and where, because ATM it looks completely random. And once you've figured it out, learn how to iterate the characters in a string, instead of asking people here to come up with a solution. "I need XYZ, can someone do it for me" isn't going to fly on this site.

Comment: Mat, I'm at a complete loss, I know asking for a solution is cheap, that why i'm asking for anything to point me in the right direction.

Comment: Can you format the input/output better?  You have `G11R`, and want that to be `G 11R`? Also, you could use a relatively long `IF` statement using `MID()` to check for each character, no?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because I wanted to see if I could do it with a formula:

```
=LEFT(IF(OR(ISERROR(--LEFT(A1)),AGGREGATE(14,6,ROW(INDIRECT("1:" & LEN(A1)))/(ISNUMBER(--MID(A1,ROW(INDIRECT("1:" & LEN(A1))),1))),1)-AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW(INDIRECT("1:" & LEN(A1)))/(ISNUMBER(--MID(A1,ROW(INDIRECT("1:" & LEN(A1))),1))),1)=3),LEFT(A1)," ") &REPT(" ",MAX(2 - (AGGREGATE(14,6,ROW(INDIRECT("1:" & LEN(A1)))/(ISNUMBER(--MID(A1,ROW(INDIRECT("1:" & LEN(A1))),1))),1)-AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW(INDIRECT("1:" & LEN(A1)))/(ISNUMBER(--MID(A1,ROW(INDIRECT("1:" & LEN(A1))),1))),1)),0)) & RIGHT(MID(A1,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW(INDIRECT("1:" & LEN(A1)))/(ISNUMBER(--MID(A1,ROW(INDIRECT("1:" & LEN(A1))),1))),1),AGGREGATE(14,6,ROW(INDIRECT("1:" & LEN(A1)))/(ISNUMBER(--MID(A1,ROW(INDIRECT("1:" & LEN(A1))),1))),1)-AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW(INDIRECT("1:" & LEN(A1)))/(ISNUMBER(--MID(A1,ROW(INDIRECT("1:" & LEN(A1))),1))),1)+1),3) & MID(A1,AGGREGATE(14,6,ROW(INDIRECT("1:" & LEN(A1)))/(ISNUMBER(--MID(A1,ROW(INDIRECT("1:" & LEN(A1))),1))),1)+1,LEN(A1))&"      ",6)
```

[image]

Just to show, I replaced all the spaces in the formula with `-`.

[image]